# I am working with strings in C and have the following query regarding input of strings

Tags: c, string

Is it right to say:

1. When we use `scanf()` for string input and press enter the newline character is not stored in the array instead the null character is stored at the end of the array. Also the new line character still remains in the buffer memory.
2. When we use `fgets()` for string input and press enter the newline character is stored(at second last position) in the array along with the null character(at the end). Also now there is no newline character in the buffer memory.

Comment: The second is dependent on the size argument of `fgets` as it relates to data onthe input stream. Input data exceeding that size-less-one before a newline is encountered can terminate the string and still keep the newline within the input stream (because it has not been consumed yet).

Comment: How `scanf` drains the input stream and what it stores in your target variables depends on the format specifier you use to process the input stream. It is possible to read everything in the file, if that's really what you want to do. Search for "scanf format specifiers" to find lots of docs on the topic.